# Return a random line from a file when user enters a specific text

Tags: python, beginner

I am a beginner trying to fetch a random line from a file and wondering if this code can be improved. Should I use try and catch in this case? Should I take a parameter for the function "quote"? How can I take several alternatives for `searchText`? (E.g. "hello", "hi" or "hey" but one is enough to return true.)

```
def getInputFromUser(inputText, verifier, error=None):
    """
    General function to get input from the user, repeating the question until verifier returns true
    """
    while True:
        userInput = input(inputText)
        if not verifier or verifier(userInput):
            return userInput
        elif error:
            print(error)

def quote():
    """
    Return a random line from a file if user enters the text "hello"
    """
    searchText = "hello"
    text = getInputFromUser("Enter a sentence with the words 'hello', 'hi' or 'hey': ", lambda inputText: inputText)

    if searchText in text:
        lineFetched = random.choice(open('myquotes.txt').readlines())
        print("My quote: ", lineFetched)
    else:
        quote()
```

Comment: `"Enter a sentence with the word "hello"': "` is broken — please fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When working with files, you should wrap `open` calls in a `with` statement like this:

```
if search_text in text:
    with open('myquotes.txt') as fh:
        line_fetched = random.choice(fh.readlines())
    print("My quote: ", line_fetched)
else:
    quote()
```

If you want to make it possible to match any of multiple words like "hello", "hi",
then you'd need a helper function, for example:

```
def text_contains_any_of(text, words):
    for term in words:
        if term in text:
            return True
    return False
```

And then change your code to use this:

```
words = ("hello", "hi")

if text_contains_any_of(text, words):
    with open('myquotes.txt') as fh:
        line_fetched = random.choice(fh.readlines())
    print("My quote: ", line_fetched)
```

In the above examples I renamed the variable and method names to follow [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: @ janos Thank you! How should I assign multiple words to "words"?  As a list or one string?

Comment: A list or tuple. I added an example now using a tuple

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a nice `getInputFromUser()` function that can loop until the desired input is received.  Why not take proper advantage of it?

```
def quote():
    SEARCH_TEXT = "hello"
    get_input_from_user(("Enter a sentence with the word '%s': " % SEARCH_TEXT),
        lambda s: SEARCH_TEXT in s)
    with open('myquotes.txt') as f:
        print("My quote: ", random.choice(f.readlines()))
```